# Keyrock vs OpenStack

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma

I am trying to understand what are really the changes done on Keystone and Horizon forks by GING and are these needed only for the Fiware Lab (i.e. are the Fiware Lab specific)?

We are making our proper Fiware installation for Mainflux IoT Cloud: https://github.com/Mainflux/mainflux, and we are using Orion and IoT Agents. We want to add security layer with Wilma and IDM, and we are wondering if we need Keyrock modifications, or we can use vanilla Keystone and Horizon from OpenStack directly.

Will Wilma work with unchanged Keystone and Horizon from OpenStack?

BR,
Drasko

Answer (score 2):

we've introduce several extensions such us OAuth2, SCIM, user-registration, two factor authentication... We have also modified the UX to fit FIWARE Lab look&feel. And also some administration tools for region management, emails, etc. Wilma will work with vanilla Keystone if you configure it to use keystone tokens. But not with oauth2 tokens.

BR

Comment: Can you please explain us what you mean by "user-registration" part that you added on the top of vanilla Keystone (i.e. what was missing in Keystone and you added)?

Comment: We have added an extension to enable users auto-registration. This includes captcha validation, password strength checker, email verification, etc